# Amazon Fire TV Remote Not Pausing ExoPlayer When Controls Hidden

Tags: android, exoplayer, amazon-fire-tv

I'm working on an Android library which is just a simple video player wrapping ExoPlayer. When using an Amazon Fire TV I can navigate my app using the remote (the directional pad switches between elements in my view) and I can control the player (the play/pause button will toggle the playing state and the seek buttons work as intended).... so long as the control bar is visible

After 3 seconds or so the control bar auto-hides, and the remote control becomes non-responsive

Is there an appropriate fix for this, or do I need to manually detect key presses on the remote and show the control bar? I feel like this is the kind of thing Amazon's port of ExoPlayer should have resolved

### Update

I extended the `PlayerView` class and overrode the `dispatchKeyEvent` method to see what was being seen:

```
public class Test extends PlayerView {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        Log.debug("***** KEY EVENT: " + String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()) + " *********");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Doing this and pressing the play button on the remote I noticed:

- When the control bar was visible, a `KeyEvent` with a `keyCode` value of `85` was dispatched
- When the control bar was hidden, **this method never triggered**

I skimmed through the methods available to `PlayerView` to see if any were helpful, but nothing seemed worthwhile:

- `setControllerAutoShow` - determines if control bar is shown when video first starts
- `setControllerHideDuringAds` - determines if the control bar is visible while an ad is playing
- `setControllerHideOnTouch` - irrelevant on FireTV (no touch events) but hides the control bar if you tap the video
- `setControllerHideTimeoutMs` - can delay the hiding of the control bar, but otherwise doesn't let me bring it back after it's hidden
- `showController` - can forcibly reveal the controller in code, allowing me to pause the video, but I without being able to see keyup events I can't properly call this when a button is pressed on the remote control

Ultimately I just want this to behave like the Netflix or Hulu apps -- the control bar goes away after a few seconds of inactivity but if you press the pause button the control bar comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expanded a bit on your solution to let all the controls work - both the player's and the activity's - since it was not possible to exit the activity anymore and also, on different devices such as phones, it wasn't possible to operate the volume control... this makes everything work, both on the Fire devices and on other devices. I hope it is helpful is someone else stubles into this.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    // this sends them to the playerView but also to the activity - whoever wants it first
    return playerView.dispatchKeyEvent(event) || super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer, but it's not exactly a beautiful one. For some reason (I still want to know why, and if someone could explain why then I would gladly accept their answer over mine) when the control bar disappears the `PlayerView` loses focus, and keyboard events are no longer sent to it. However all keyboard events are still seen by the ***Activity*** hosting the `PlayerView`. So I added the following to my Activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        playerView.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
```

Now whether the control bar is visible or not, the player still responds to all key events. However:

- This requires editing the activity, which means anyone using my player library will need to know about this extra step to integrate the player properly
- This does not explain why the player is losing focus, it merely circumvents the issue

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for this post, I tried using this solution in the app I am writing.... while it seems to correctly intercept the remote key presses and redirect them to the player view (so the controls re-appear), the side effect I get is that the activity doesn't receive them anymore.... hence it's not possible, for example, to click 'back' and exit from the player anymore... :-( how did you solve this?

Comment: I answer myself: adding super.dispatchKeyEvent(event) before returning from your overridden function seems to do the trick and dispatch events to both player and activity...

Comment: One more question on this: do you know if the buttons for forward and back (with the video controls) can be selected and 'clicked' in the UI? It appears that they don't, but the equivalent physical buttons on the remote do work. Have you stumbled into this limitation as well? Thanks!

Comment: @DanieleMuscetta Unfortunately I don't have an answer for whether or not the forward and back buttons can be clicked. This project has been handed off to another dev so I'm no longer working on the Android SDK nor do I have access to an AmazonFire at the moment.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the answer anyways :-) I'll figure it out....